# How to set date format(dd/MM/YYYY) in asp.net entity frame work

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to set date format(dd/MM/yyyy) in asp.net entity frame work. Its working only "MM/dd/yyyy" format.can any body help me?

```
`[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Enquiry_Date { get; set; }
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Enquiry_Date, new { @class = "jqueryui-marker-datepicker", @id = "txt_Enquiry_Date" }) 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Enquiry_Date)
      <script>
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#txt_Enquiry_Date").datepicker({
                            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                            changeMonth: true,
                            yearRange: "-100:+100",
                            changeYear: true
                        }).datepicker("setDate","0");
                        $("#txt_Expect_Delivery_Date").datepicker({
                            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                            changeMonth: true,
                            yearRange: "-100:+100",
                            changeYear: true
                        }).datepicker("setDate", "0");

                    });
                </script>`[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Date Time Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074055/c-sharp-date-time-formatting)

Comment: here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531735/bootstrap-datepicker-asp-net-mvc-not-work-in-my-code-any/43541603#43541603

Comment: change to 'format'

Comment: It is not working only on chrome browser?

Answer (score 1):

If the date time passed to controller is `passedDateValue`

`var convertedDate = passedDateValue.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but in view(in design) it does not take dd/MM/yyyy format."The field Enquiry_Date must be a date" error message is display.

Comment: it does not take means? You told you want the date converted in entity framework. Now you're saying view? @TrilochanSahu

Comment: sorry,i am new in mvc so am unable to explain exact problem.i will send screnn shot of error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.
in jquery.validate.js write below code(now its working fine)
date: function (value, element) {

```
       // return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
        var d = value.split("/");
        return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date((/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) ? d[1] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[2] : value));
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
YourDate.ToString("dd MM yyyy");
```